# #mysql I cant use LIMIT in sub query to SELECT this result

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many Conditions like {ar, nat, eco, ..etc}.
Every condition can be {"1" or "0"}.
I want to get this table in categories, every category has 3 records without repeating the record in the categories.
I thought the code will be like this:

for the first category:

```
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE ar="1" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

for the second category:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE nat="1" AND id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table WHERE ar="1" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT  3;
```

and so on..
[this is the image of what I need from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB02Z.png)
Any help?

Comment: can you share your create table query

Comment: `code
CREATE TABLE table_name (
id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ar   ENUM("0", "1") DEFAULT "0",
nat   ENUM("0", "1") DEFAULT "0",
eco          ENUM("0", "1") DEFAULT "0",
sport  ENUM("0", "1") DEFAULT "0"
);
`

Comment: " this is the image of what I need from the table" I didn't clear about this statement. because your out table like actual table only. 
your question is not understandable, Please ask clearly.